# Javascript_include_tag vs scoping the javascript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a view, I see this piece of code:

```
  = javascript_include_tag 'recipes/recipe'
```

I also have read scoping Javascript to specific files... which in my mind is:
1. creating classes in the html.
2. writing javascript that waits for that class to load before executing.

I read [this](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/)

But I guess that the above scoping of javascript doesn't prevent the Javascript from loading on every page... it simply just doesn't run the Javascript code unless the page has certain classes.

I am currently trying to read [this](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) and I wonder if the above tag should be used or just use the Rails asset pipeline.

**My questions:**

1. Is there a drawback to using javascript_include_tag over the asset pipeline by using the application.js file?
2. Does this javascript file show up in the sources/sources tab in Chrome devtools?